# use FileVisitor in a recursive fashion?

Tags: java, performance, filesystems, java-7

I'm in a dilemma between the 'old' way and the 'new' faster 1.7 way of scanning directories.

I need to scan all directories on a drive and build a similar tree structure. There is no problem in 1.6 (except it's 10 times slower), but with FileFisitor I have some big hurdles.

How do I know beforehand how many items (files+subdirectories) a directory contains?

- Old way: `File[] files = path.listFiles();` and `files.length` is the answer.
- New way: in callback function `public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path path, BasicFileAttributes bfa){}`, where is the count?

Using a scalable array (ArrayList) for *each* subdirectory will definitely hurt both performance and the already large memory footprint, hence I need to use regular fixed-length arrays. An alternative I've been pondering is using a reusable master array and once I know the length, copy it to a destination array. This however conflicts with the recursive nature, and the fact that directories and file are walked interleaved instead of grouped. I'd need a master array for every recursion depth (potentially infinite) unless I can make it walk directories first, then files (which my research says can't be done.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would really question this assumption:

> Using a scalable array (ArrayList) for each subdirectory will
>   definitely hurt both performance and the already large memory
>   footprint

What basis do you have for this ? Note that your performance will likely be limited (or at least affected) by the speed of access to your filesystem.

I think (as for most question sof this nature) that you try a simple extensible solution and identify any issues for real, rather than make assumptions in advance.

Comment: +1 cost of an ArrayList is less than 1000th of the cost of a disk access.